# Including csv or erb files in a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm looking at a tutorial on how to create and upload a ruby gem, but I'm kind of confused on how to include data files like .csv or .erb so that when I do `gem build gemname.gemspec` and `gem push gemname-0.1.0.gem` it will include in the gem package(if it's allowed). I tried it and the gem is functional, so I'm just looking for a way to include the data files. The code of the class in the game is not important, it's a very basic one from the tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some gem building toolkits will do this for you, like `jeweller` or `hoe`. I think the built-in one is mostly a manual process.

Comment: "if it's allowed"  It turns out it is allowed - I stumbled on this question as I was using `git ls-files lib/*` to include my ERB files, but then found that I had to actually add them to the git repository first before they could be included in the gem.